# Why am I getting an 'is not a function' error in this JS class?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this little class:

```
var SwitchHider;

SwitchHider = {
  inputSelector: 'body.socials input',
  _showOrHideClosestSwitch: function(element) {
    var socialUrl, swich_wrapper;
    socialUrl = $(element).val();
    swich_wrapper = $(element).closest('.white-box').find('.switch');
    if (socialUrl.length > 0) {
      return swich_wrapper.show();
    } else {
      return swich_wrapper.hide();
    }
  },
  _bindCallbacks: function() {
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      return $(self.inputSelector).each(function(index, element) {
        return self._showOrHideClosestSwitch(element);
      });
    });
    return $(document).on('change keyup input', self.inputSelector, function() {
      return self._showOrHideClosestSwitch(this);
    });
  },
  initialize: function() {
    var self;
    self = this;
    this._bindCallbacks();
  }
};

window.SwitchHider = SwitchHider;

$(function() {
  SwitchHider.initialize();
});
```

(it's compiled from this CoffeeScript file, hope it makes sense):

```
SwitchHider =
  inputSelector: 'body.socials input'

  _showOrHideClosestSwitch: (element) ->
    socialUrl = $(element).val()
    swich_wrapper = $(element).closest('.white-box').find('.switch')
    if socialUrl.length > 0
      swich_wrapper.show()
    else
      swich_wrapper.hide()

  _bindCallbacks: ->
    $(document).on 'ready', ->
      $(self.inputSelector).each (index, element) ->
        self._showOrHideClosestSwitch(element)

    $(document).on 'change keyup input', self.inputSelector, ->
      self._showOrHideClosestSwitch(@)

  initialize: ->
    self = this
    @_bindCallbacks()
    return

# Send to global namespace
window.SwitchHider = SwitchHider

# DOM Ready
$ ->
  SwitchHider.initialize()
  return
```

And when event is triggered - it gives this error:

```
TypeError: self._showOrHideClosestSwitch is not a function
```

Does anyone see why? It's my first attempt to write classes like that, don't fully understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you post the CoffeeScript? I don't see where `self` is in scope of where you are using it. I think your CoffeeScript code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not in scope. This is begging for a class syntax:

```
class SwitchHider
  @inputSelector: 'body.socials input'
  constructor: ->
    $(document).on 'ready', =>
      $(SwitchHider.inputSelector).each (index, element) =>
        @_showOrHideClosestSwitch(element)

    $(document).on 'change keyup input', SwitchHider.inputSelector, (e) =>
      @_showOrHideClosestSwitch(e.target)


  _showOrHideClosestSwitch: (element) ->
    socialUrl = $(element).val()
    swich_wrapper = $(element).closest('.white-box').find('.switch')
    if socialUrl.length > 0
      swich_wrapper.show()
    else
      swich_wrapper.hide()

# Send to global namespace
window.SwitchHider = SwitchHider

# DOM Ready
$ ->
  new SwitchHider()
```

I used the `=>` to handle proper scope of `this`

Comment: This could be further simplified but I wanted to illustrate some important CoffeeScript patterns

Comment: Used thiis code, but modified it a bit using suggestions from first answer. Both answers were good.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is only defined as a local variable under `initialize`. It won't be available to other methods.

```
  initialize: function() {
    var self;
    self = this;
    this._bindCallbacks();
  }
```

You'll either have to define a local `self` within each method that needs it:

```
  _showOrHideClosestSwitch: (element) ->
    self = this
    # ...

  _bindCallbacks: ->
    self = this
    # ...
```

Or, you can use [fat arrows to bind](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) each callback to the surrounding context and use `this` or `@` instead:

```
  _bindCallbacks: ->
    $(document).on 'ready', =>
      $(@inputSelector).each (index, element) =>
        @_showOrHideClosestSwitch(element)

    $(document).on 'change keyup input', self.inputSelector, (ev) =>
      @_showOrHideClosestSwitch(ev.currentTarget)
```

In the event handler, the `Element` that's normally the context value can still be retrieved via [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).